# Application badge disappears when Phonegap app is opened?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm using the "Push" plugin for my Phonegap app. The app is compiled through Phonegap Build, so I never actually use XCode. I specify I want the plugin by putting this in my `config.xml`:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.1.1" />
```

I'm able to set the badge when I push a notification server side; however, when the app on the phone is opened, the badge is cleared. I would like to control when the badge is cleared manually. Does using this plugin via Phonegap Build force this behavior?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601874/phonegap-pushplugin-reset-badge-after-opening-app

Answer (score 1):

It's intended behaviour of the pushplugin plugin.
You've to modify the Objective-C code.

Here is the full answer: [Phonegap PushPlugin reset badge after opening app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601874/phonegap-pushplugin-reset-badge-after-opening-app/25632172#25632172)

Answer (score 0):

The [new API](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md) for this plugin allows you to specify this preference at initialisation:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
  ios: {
    badge: true,
    clearBadge: false
  }
});
```