# Phonegap PushPlugin reset badge after opening app

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

How can I prevent PushPlugin from reseting my badge count to 0 after entering the app from the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across this problem as well.

For some reason this is intended behaviour. It's because in the *com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin,* the badge get cleared to 0 when the app get active again.

I ended up editing the plugin:

In the file "*AppDelegate+notification.m*", in the method:

```
"- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {"
```

Change line ~90:

```
//zero badge
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

to:

```
//zero badge
//application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

(I just ended up commenting it out).